# Are base classes in inheritance copied to the derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

as the title says : are base classes in inheritance copied to the derived class I mean like `#include` the code from the base class is copied to the derived class or just an object from the base class is created and the children class just use is it at runtime ?

Comment: What is the distinction?

Comment: if they're created and the derived class just uses it it will be more like composition (special type of composition)

Comment: I don't see how. Are you getting confused between semantics and implementation?

Comment: A class is an object factory. Classes cannot be copied. A program can copy objects. An object of class `Derived` contains an instance of class `Base` as a subobject. We use the word "instance" rather than "copy" to prevent confusion with the actual copy operation.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're asking whether the base class' declaration & definition are implicitly copied into the derived class' declaration & definition, and become a part of the derived class' declaration & definition during compilation, correct?

Comment: @JustinTime that's i was asking that that's why I used the #include example

Comment: Thought so.  That's one way of looking at what goes on behind the scenes, although probably not the best way, as it's relatively easy to misread as something else.  Basically, derivation follows the "is-a" rule: an instance of a derived class is, via polymorphism, also a valid instance of the base class, which by extension means that the derived class implicitly includes every member of the base class (although only base class member functions can access `private` base class members).  So, in this regard, the derived class can be said to implicitly include the base's definition & declaration.

Comment: A more accurate way of looking at it, however, is that the derived class is built around the base class (as an expansion, not a wrapper), and has the base class as its core.  Think about it like a building with an extra wing added on: the original building is the base class, and the finished product, with the new wing, is the derived class.  It's still the same building, but _more_.  You could also look at it as the base class being a naked human being, and the derived class being that same person, but with clothes on.  The base is still a human being, but now they're a _clothed_ human being.

Comment: That's also how polymorphism works: for a base class `Base` and a derived class `Derived`, a `Base*` can point to a `Derived` because if you strip the derived components off, what you're left with is the base.  The `Derived` components are built around the `Base` components, so that every instance of `Derived` can also be used as an instance of `Base`.

Comment: `Derived` implicitly has every member function of `Base` (and provides the full interface), and every member variable of `Base`.  If `Base` is a hamburger, `Derived` might be a hamburger with bacon; it's still a hamburger (the "is-a" rule), but now it has bacon, too.  If `Base` is a science teacher, `Derived` might be a chemistry teacher. They still teach science, but now they specialise in a particular type of science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Are base classes in inheritance copied to the derived class?

No, they aren't copied. They are intrinsically merged into the derived class.

> or just an object from the base class is created and the children class just use is it at runtime ?

That concept describes it closest, but:

No there's no *object from the base class is created* separately. An object of the derived class is created and completely includes it's base class features.

Comment: Yet, from another point of view, they _are_ copied. They're copied for every instance of `Derived`, and every instance of `Base`, even! We could use pretty much any abstract scenario to describe how classes are implemented, and none of them have any inherent value other the over, nor are any of them in any way useful to discuss.

Comment: @PreferenceBean _"Yet, from another point of view ..."_ Shangri-La? Well ,from point of code view, there's nothing copied, but just shared.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is all abstract ways of looking at it.

I think its fair to say that the compiler calculates the `size` of the derived type by including the base type's definition in its calculation. So it allocates enough memory for both.

It then *constructs* the base class in the first part of the allocated memory by calling its constructor and then *constructs* the derived class in the second part of the allocated memory using the derived class's constructor.

At the end of the day you end up with a chunk of memory (an object) that is large enough to hold the base class member objects and the derived class member objects. The generated member functions each have their member variable address offsets (from the start of the allocated memory) calculated accordingly.

So I don't think anything is actually 'copied' as such, each part is *constructed* into its portion of the allocated memory.

Two cookie cutters and an extra large piece of pastry.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are programming language definitions used by compiler to mount the code. Only the class objects instantiated take a memory space on runtime.

At this time, the full object's class (derived and base classes) is allocated and associated with the instantiated object.

So, it does not make sense to think about base classes be copied to derived classes, once for each object created its corresponding full class (derived + base classes) is allocated, and of course, each object has its own instance and does not share base classes members data with another objects of same class.

If you want to force two objects to share data you have to define some of its members as pointers to the shared data.

Comment: so they're laid down in memory each piece on it's (the base part and the derived part of the class) and they're just connected together , does ABI have anything to do with this ?